# MySQL Fulltext search query matching ALL words still returns partial matches

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm having the identical issue that [this poster had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956323/mysql-fulltext-boolean-mode-search-returns-too-many-results), however the accepted answer didn't resolve my issue. Basically I'm trying to match my "title" column with ALL of the words in a fulltext search query, yet it's still returning partial matches. I recently transferred my MySQL database tables to a new web host, and my fulltext search isn't behaving as it was on my old server. I'm assuming there might be a setting difference, but I can't seem to locate it. Fulltext is enabled, my ft_min_word_len is set at 3, and yet the following MySQL query is still garnering partial matches:

```
SELECT title, MATCH (title) AGAINST ("more pink") AS relevance
FROM discography
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ("+more +pink" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

The above code returns the below set, the first 7 titles are:

```
Under The Pink & More Pink
Under The Pink Tour All Pass
Under The Pink Tour Guest Pass
Under The Pink Tour Aftershow Pass
Under The Pink Tour After Show Pass
Under The Pink
Under The Pink
```

How can I omit the partial matches? Is there something I'm missing? The results are even worse if I put the SELECT statement in Boolean mode, since that sets the relevance into a binary 1 or 0:

```
SELECT title, MATCH (title) AGAINST ("+more +pink" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM discography
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ("+more +pink" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

First 7 titles are:

```
Under The Pink
Under The Pink
Under The Pink
Under The Pink
Under The Pink
Under The Pink
Under The Pink & More Pink
```

Despite using the + operator, it doesn't seem to be narrowing my results. Any help would be welcome, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that it should necessarily matter, but could you try using single quotes instead of double quotes, e.g. use `WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+more +pink' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea @TimBiegeleisen. I tried your suggestion and it still garners the same results.

Comment: I think you should try to make your question reproducible, as what you are seeing should not be happening.  Are you sure you created the full text index properly?

Comment: Perhaps I did not do it properly, but I queried the following: "ALTER TABLE discography ADD FULLTEXT(title)". I received no errors from doing this, and I see "FULLTEXT" on the column structure enabled. Is there anything else that should be done? Also, if you can expound upon what you mean by reproducible, I'd be eager to oblige. I can certainly make a live example on my web host, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I upvoted you, which is as much as I can do sadly, because I see nothing obvious wrong with your logic.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you. I will try to give a more concrete example soon.

Comment: I'm sorry, but cannot reproduce the above behaviour in mysql v5.5 nor 5.7. I'm not aware of any setting that would change the meaning of the + operator in mysql.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow. If nothing else you and Tim have confirmed for me that there's nothing more I can do codewise, and I'm not missing something obvious. I'll just have to maybe call the web host and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel silly now. My table uses MyISAM, and according to the documentation, "more" is on the stopwords list. So that's why that search is picking up on partial matches. Thanks everyone for the help.

*EDIT*

If anyone is curious how to "go around" a stopwords list on shared hosting when programming your own search engine on your website, I recommend a similar technique that I used to get around my "ft_min_word_len" setting. Create a separate search column that saves a duplicate all of the values in the column or columns you wish to be searched via Fulltext. Create an include file that stores all the [stopwords listed for your database type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) into an array. Before saving the values into your dedicated search column, loop through each individual word in your column values and check if any exist in the stopwords array using the include file. If any values include stopwords, add a character onto the stopword at the end (I chose "z"). Then when a search is triggered, loop the search terms through the same stopwords array and check to see if any include stopwords. If any search words are in the stopwords array, once again add the same character you chose to add to the end of the stopwords in your search column ("z" in this case). After looping through the array and making the necessary alterations to the search terms, you may search your dedicated search column without fear of your stopwords being ignored. Of course, I don't use my search column for any display purposes, only searching.